# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property ‘placeholder’ of null at window.onload

Tags: javascript

I've looked at earlier similar questions but this is slightly different. I've run into users at one organization who are getting this error when they try to register for an event. I haven't been able to replicate it, our platform Support (Blackbaud) has not been able to replicate it, I haven't heard of anyone else running into the problem. But when folks from this one organization try to register the form shows "Error: Please fix the errors below and try again." Generally, errors are always highlighted in red, but for them nothing is being highlighted and all fields are completed correctly. They've tried different browsers. They sent me a screen shot of the browser dev console for two events and both had this particular "Uncaught TypeError" message.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be going on with that organization's computers that would be causing this problem for them and no one else? I'm not a coder and this is a managed product that I can't change the code in.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You probably have some object that the developer expected to be non-null when they accessed the property `object.placeholder`, but the object was null, hence the error. Without seeing the code, it's impossible to help you debug this further. If you can't change the code (are using it as a library) but have access to code or some component of your system that uses the library incorrectly, then that's where to try for a fix.

Comment: @ggorlen - I can't really try for a fix as the code is controlled by the product owner and I've already engaged their support team. And I know they aren't about to go in and change the code any time soon--maybe a fix in 6 mos. if they can figure it out. I'm just trying to get any ideas as to what could be going on with one set of users that would cause them to be the only ones who are having a problem.

Comment: Gotcha. The error you describe is about as generic and typical as it gets, though, so there's no telling what could be causing it for one group of users or another. Whatever is causing the error is totally application-dependent and specific to their code. The fact that it's inside `window.onload` tells you that the property they are accessing is inside a closure and can't be manipulated from the console.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. Gives me some perspective.